Chrome extension - update dom on x.com (twitter)
i working on an extension to use myself - that i intend to inject into the Twitter/X
and got to a weird situation that i can't overpass.
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabID,tabStatus) => {
   
   if(tabStatus.status === "complete")// && loaded == false)
   {
     console.log("tabStatus.status: " + tabStatus.status);
     console.log("tabStatus.loaded: " + loaded);

     let tabProps = await getTabProperties(tabID); 
     if(tabProps.url.startsWith(twitterUrl))
     {
    
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
         injectImmediately: false,
         target : {tabId : tabID},
         args: [1],
         //runAt:"document_end",
         func : injectedFunction,
       });

    

async function injectedFunction(a) {
    console.log("count after delay: " + document.querySelectorAll(`[role="tab"]`).length);

//this will not find anything: outputs is zero.

that document query selector doesn't return nothing - I can understand that at the moment the script is run the doom is not loaded yet.
i try to use a delay - and that did the trick but not always (!) but it doesn't seems the right way.
is there any way for me to understand when the document is fully loaded?


The code you've shown is incomplete. 2) To return something you need to use return 'foo' in the function and await executeScript as shown here. Note that DOM elements cannot be transferred. 3) There's no need for the background script here. Declare content_scripts in manifest.json for "*://x.com/*" and "*://twitter.com/*", then use MutationObserver inside to wait for the element to appear.


i'm not actually to return nothing - only to manipulate the dom - the issue is that my query selector doesn't return nothing. editing the code to be more clear

The element is added dynamically, after the URL changes. Use point #3 in my comment.
